# Запись константы в одно из полей sql-таблицы

Tags: python, база-данных, pandas, dataframe

Добрый день.

В pandas есть очень полезный метод to_sql, который позволяет легко залить весь датафрейм в sql-таблицу.

Однако в sql-таблице, куда я заливаю данные, есть ещё один столбец, которого нет в моём датафрейме, и значение, которое туда будет писаться - одно и то же в рамках каждой конкретной процедуры сброса данных.

Как-то не хочется специально для этого создавать в датафрейме на несколько миллионов строк специальный столбец, в котором будет одно и то же число.

Есть какой-то способ передать в метод to_sql константное значение?

Comment: снимите в БД обязательность атрибута (которого у вас нет) для строки, запишите свой "датафрейм" в таблицу, пропишите в sql столбец с  "константой". Можете также отделить "датафрейм" от "константы" и хранить таблицу в которой данные полностью соответствуют "датафрейму",а "константу добавить с помощью представления или на этапе использования таблицы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

насколько мне известно единственное что мы можем сделать это добавить виртуальный столбец в момент сохранения DF в БД:

```
const_val = 10
df.assign(new_col_name=const_val).to_sql(...)
```

т.е. столбец будет добавлен в памяти временно и после окончания `.to_sql()` он будет удален из памяти...

---

Также можно попробовать указать для данного столбца `DEFAULT ...` в БД и использовать `if_exists='append'`:

```
df.to_sql(..., if_exists='append')
```